# How to import a map style template from mapbox to flutter using flutter_map?

Tags: flutter, mapbox, flutter-web, mapbox-android

I'm trying to add a map in my flutter app through flutter_map package. 
I tried to import this mapbox style : 
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/tomjohn/cj5yp5pln0cqb2ruhy6w99j91.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidG9tam9obiIsImEiOiJxQ2RydWRNIn0.mYKLvmkrBlBKiQZdhNa31A#10.39/55.8548/-4.1836

by doing this :

```
FlutterMap(
              options: new MapOptions(
                center: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
                zoom: 13.0,
              ),
              layers: [
                new TileLayerOptions(
                  urlTemplate: "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/"
                      "{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={accessToken}",
                ),
                new MarkerLayerOptions(
                  markers: [
                    new Marker(
                      width: 80.0,
                      height: 80.0,
                      point: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
                      builder: (ctx) =>
                      new Container(
                        child: new FlutterLogo(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

But it is throwing this exception :

> Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.

Comment: The code that you have provided does not load the style you have mentioned. What would you like to achieve? Load a mapbox map with the style you mentioned, or add another TileLayer?

Comment: Can we add google maps APIs in flutter_map package ?

Answer (score 3):

To import mapbox tile:

In your mapbox style sharing option (under developer resources), choose "Third party" and select "CARTO" in dropdown button. Then you can copy the link and paste it as `urlTemplate`.

After that, add this:

```
TileLayerOptions(
                  urlTemplate:<PASTE_URL_HERE>,
                  additionalOptions: {
                    'accessToken': <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>,
                    'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8'
                  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MapboxMap(
     styleString: "*****",
     myLocationEnabled: true,
     rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
     scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
     tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
     onMapCreated: (MapboxMapController controller){
        _controller = controller;
     },
     initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
       target: LatLng(***,***), zoom: 15),
     ),
```